# How to programmatically open jquery accordion content panel

Tags: jquery

I want to extend the default behavior of the jquery accordion and add a NEXT button inside the content panels. When the user clicks NEXT button inside the content panel, the accordion should open the next item.

I was able to locate the next item like this `$(this).parent().next()` but having trouble triggering the actual action.

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3><a href="#">Item 1</a></h3>
   <div>Item 1 content<br />
      <div onclick="$(this).parent().next().show();">NEXT</div>
   </div>
   <h3><a href="#">Item 2</a></h3>
   <div>Item 2 content<br />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Next item inside the same content panel, or the next content panel?

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().next().toggle()` or `$(this).parent().next().show()`

Comment: Because the `<h3>` is what's next after the parent `<div>`... `$(this).parent().next('div').toggle()/show()`

Comment: @AndrewPeacock `.next()` doesn't work like that. For that functionality, you would need `.nextUntil("div").next("div")`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If this is the jQuery UI Accordion widget, you should be using it's built-in methods.

```
var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
function openNextAccordionPanel() {
    var current = $accordion.accordion("option","active"),
        maximum = $accordion.find("h3").length,
        next = current+1 === maximum ? 0 : current+1;
    // $accordion.accordion("activate",next); // pre jQuery UI 1.10
    $accordion.accordion("option","active",next);
}
```

html:

```
<div onclick="openNextAccordionPanel();">NEXT</div>
```

Comment: Where? Every comma I see is for the combined `var` statement. If you replace those, `maximum` and `next` become global variables.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.10.3 and had to change the last line to: $accordion.accordion("option","active",next);

Comment: @GinjaNinja Like that? (the code in your comment is/was missing.) Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I was too lazy to look at the docs. If this isn't in them though, it should be.

Answer (score 2):

My accordion has only one content div (0 index) and on postback I'm registering the script to open again the accordion after it's recreation ($("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: true });$("#accordion").show();) to position layout where the user was before triggered the postback.

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion" style="display: none">
    <h3>ACCORDION TITLE</h3>
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="overflow: hidden">
```

Javascript function:

```
 $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 0 });

 $('.ui-accordion-content').css('height', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 0):

To have you code working perfectly, you should modify your html as follows

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3><a href="#">Item 1</a></h3>
   <div class='showable'>Item 1 content<br />
      <div onclick="$(this).parent('.showable').hide().next().show();">NEXT</div>
   </div>
   <h3><a href="#">Item 2</a></h3>
   <div class='showable'>Item 2 content<br />
   </div>
</div>
```