# Form in jQuery Accordion: how to get tab key to open next tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a dialog with a form that is split across tabs in an accordion (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9TeB/)  as an example). Right now, when the user is in the First Name field and hits the tab key to move on to the next field, it moves focus to the Okay button; what I would like to happen is that Tab 2 opens and focuses Address Line 1.  Is there an elegant way to do this, or will I have to write my own keypress handlers?

Thanks!

HTML code from the fiddle:

```
<div id=dialog title="My dialog">
    <form>
    <div id=accordion>
        <h3>Tab 1</h3>
        <div><table>
            <tr><td><label for=last-edit>Last Name:</label></td><td><input id=last-edit /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><label for=first-edit>First Name:</label></td><td><input id=first-edit /></td></tr>
        </table></div>      
        <h3>Tab 2</h3>
        <div><table>
            <tr><td><label for=add1-edit>Address 1:</label></td><td><input id=add1-edit /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><label for=add2-edit>Address 2:</label></td><td><input id=add2-edit /></td></tr>
        </table></div>      
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript from the fiddle:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 500,
    autoOpen : true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
});
$('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to tab through the `input` elements on a panel until it reaches the last `input` element. It will then open the next panel and `focus` on the first `input` element. It will continue working in a loop like that.

```
$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == '9') {
        var currentInput = $("input:focus");
        var lastInput = $(".ui-accordion-content-active input").last();
        if (currentInput[0] === lastInput[0]) {
            var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
            var current = accordion.accordion("option", "active");
            var maximum = accordion.find("h3").length;
            var next = current + 1 === maximum ? 0 : current + 1;
            accordion.accordion("option", "active", next);
            var active = $(".ui-accordion-content-active[aria-expanded=true] input")[0];
            setTimeout(function () {
                active.focus()
            }, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/E9TeB/2/). The code for determining the next panel is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041420/how-to-programmatically-open-jquery-accordion-content-panel). I haven't tested this with more than two panels, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Charlie's answer, I did the following. It avoids selecting hidden inputs and it also allows you to Shift+Tab out of the active accordion panel into the previous one and caters for any dynamic inputs that are added after page load:

```
$("#accordion").on("keydown", "input", function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var count;

    if (code == '9') {
        count = $('#accordion h3').size();
        if (count <= 1) return;

        var currentInput = $("input[type!='hidden']:focus");
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            var firstInput = $(".ui-accordion-content-active input[type!='hidden']").first();
            if (currentInput[0] === firstInput[0]) {
                var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
                var current = accordion.accordion("option", "active");
                var prev = current - 1 < 0 ? count : current - 1;
                accordion.accordion("option", "active", prev);
                active = $(".ui-accordion-content-active[aria-expanded=true] input[type!='hidden']").last();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    active.focus();
                }, 1);
            }
        } else {
            var lastInput = $(".ui-accordion-content-active input[type!='hidden']").last();
            if (currentInput[0] === lastInput[0]) {
                var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
                var current = accordion.accordion("option", "active");
                var maximum = accordion.find("h3").length;
                var next = current + 1 === maximum ? 0 : current + 1;
                accordion.accordion("option", "active", next);
                active = $(".ui-accordion-content-active[aria-expanded=true] input[type!='hidden']")[0];
                setTimeout(function() {
                    active.focus();
                }, 1);
            }
        }
    }                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to use your own keypress handlers. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/3VBbb/) for you.

```
var $accordion = $('#accordion');
$accordion.accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
});

$('#first-edit').keydown(function (e) {
    // TAB key is keyCode 9
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        openNextAccordionPanel($accordion);
    }
});


function openNextAccordionPanel($accordion) {
    var current = $accordion.accordion("option", "active"),
        maximum = $accordion.find("h3").length,
        next = current + 1 === maximum ? 0 : current + 1;
    // $accordion.accordion("activate",next); // pre jQuery UI 1.10
    $accordion.accordion("option", "active", next);
}
```