# how to control accordion event with a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this script i copied from the internet. i want to control the accordion event(close current div and open next div) with a button

```
<button> Click me to open next</button>
```

in the div instead of the

```
     <h3 id="section1">Section 1</h3>
```

.

Am new to jquery and javascript any help would be well appreciated.

this is the fiddle to my code:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mystro/nCw2A/3/)

Comment: Sounds like this question, which might be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11041420/3063706

Comment: thanks Danny but what i really want to achieve is to disable the header click so i depend on the button click to navigate the pages . Can u help with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your particular fiddle. I modified it a little bit, and bind the button click onto click on `<h3>` tags, like you were clicking them manually. From there, for every click of button, it just clicks the next `<h3>`. Consider this example:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
        //alert($(ui.newHeader).attr("id"))
        }
    });

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var current_index = $(this).parent().next('h3').index();
        if(current_index != -1) { // just checks if its the last
            $(this).parent().next('h3').trigger('click');
        } else {
            $('h3#section1').trigger('click');
        }

    });
});
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCw2A/6/)

Comment: yea thanks that what am looking for but i dont want the header click to be active so i depend only on the button to navigate the divs how would i do that

Comment: @user3093686 is this something like a step-by-step process? and with regards to that, is the button only the one to assign the opening? and regarding to the header, you dont want it the active header to white (active)?

Comment: Yes its a step-by-step process  and with regards to that i want only the button to do the openings and also i want to disable the click event behind the header so that its no longer clickable.

Comment: @user3093686 i cant find a good solution for this, some answers al over the net only disables the first header, but i have made a workaround regarding disabling headers, [check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCw2A/8/)

Comment: Thanks so much its done exactly  as i want it to . am very grateful