# Highlight active link in jQuery accordion menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

So I found this jQuery Accordion Menu code for a WordPress site I'm working on. All is working well, but when I click a submenu item and the page loads, the accordion is closed. I would like the current section to be opened on page load so you can see what page you're on.

I've tried a bunch of different things, using `.slideDown('normal')` on the class that WordPress assigns to the parent `<li>` of `.current-menu-parent`, etc. but alas nothing has worked yet. I'm not well versed with JavaScript/jQuery so hopefully someone can help me with this.

Here is the current jQuery code:

```
( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {

            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   
            var checkElement = $(this).next();

            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }

            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }

            if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;   
            }       

        });
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

[This](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/wordpress-accordion-menu-tutorial) is where I got it from.

Comment: A thought: you could set the ID of one of those as a url param (eg. domain.com/page?tab_id=5), [grab that ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery) on page load, and [programmatically open the tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041420/how-to-programmatically-open-jquery-accordion-content-panel) you'd like to display.

Comment: Isn't that info to programmatically open the tab for the jQuery accordion widget? This is just some custom code I found. Not sure if that would work in this case (like I said I'm new to jQuery so if you disagree I'll try and work with it). Thoughts?

Comment: It would definitely not be the same, but the principles would be similar. You can see the click event declared on line 315 in the tutorial page's source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your menu output, it's a little hard to tell... but what you need to do is trigger the click event for not only the page being viewed, but it's ancestors as well.  And do this outside the click event.  Something like this (your code, slightly modified):

```
( function( $ ) { $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.current-page-ancestor > a').trigger('click');
    $('.current-menu-item > a').trigger('click');

    $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {

        $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   
        var checkElement = $(this).next();

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }

        if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;   
        }       

    });
});

} )( jQuery );
```

As a side note, which I know doesn't answer your direct question... but this whole process could be done easier with the use of CSS transitions over JS... and is much more reliable and less dependent on JS.  You do use a small amount of JS to add/remove a class, but the css controls the animations.

And if JS is disabled, you can have a much more graceful degradation... using the css :hover pseudo to allow the accordion to still function.  Also, you can use the default WordPress menu classes to have the accordion open on page load through css, rather than relying on JS to find which one should be opened...  Just a thought.

Comment: Hey thanks, that got it working... but only when I put the .trigger line you wrote AFTER the .click function.

As for the CSS suggestion. Yeah I agree, next time perhaps. :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked out.  It makes sense to call those after the function gets created as it wouldn't know the function even exists! :)  Didn't think that one through...

Comment: Hey, I know this is a very old post, but the code doesnt work for me even if I put .trigger after .click function - can anyone please help!